# What happend when I lock my screen and unlock go back to my application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, screen

I found when I lock my phone screen and unlock,The xaml page seems to be reload.This is not the point,the point is the whole program I wrote is just like fresh restart.It is true?What can I do with this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read the [Execution Model Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817008%28VS.92%29.aspx).  Your app is getting Tombstoned.  You need to [handle this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.deactivated%28VS.92%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

An application in the foreground can continue to run when the phone screen is locked by setting the [PhoneApplicationService.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.applicationidledetectionmode%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) property.
By setting up your application to run when the phone screen is locked, a user is able to access the application quickly upon unlock. However, when your application runs under a locked screen, it could consume power outside of the user's control. For this reason, your application must minimize power usage when running under a locked screen

Comment: My application can run under background?What about user push start button and run another application?

Comment: Your app can run when you lock phone's screen, by default your app is tombstoning.